# Was it wrong for a man to reject both married and unmarried woman's sexual or romantic advances?

Tags: women, sex

I [read that](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/48382/was-it-possible-to-reject-a-girl-if-she-approached-a-man-in-ancient-hindu-india), it was considered as wrong for a man to reject a woman's sexual/romantic advances on him.

Although in the linked question, it is written that it was only for a Kshatriya man. But I think It was applicable even for brahmins. As Ravan's mother Kaikesi too had approached Vishrava. And Vrishrava couldn't reject her due to the above principle.(I had watched this story of Vishrava and Kaikesi [in Hindi serial](https://www.jiocinema.com/tv-shows/shrimad-bhagwat-mahapuran/1/the-birth-of-the-devious-ravan/3163152) Shreemad Bhagwad MahaPurana)

My question is - Was this principle applicable to both married and unmarried woman ? i.e. A man couldn't reject a woman's advances on him.
Here I am not discussing if the woman will incur sin or not. Most probably she will (at least when she is married).
But I am concerned only about the man.

Also I am not saying that this principle should be applied even in present modern world as polygamy has been legally banned for men. Plus there are many laws today because of which a man can land in trouble if he follows the above principle of not rejecting a woman.

Comment: Right and wrong is a matter of ethics, nothing to do with moksha or anything. One cannot land in trouble if he/she follows the laws of the land and time.

Comment: lol, right and wrong have EVERYTHING to do with moksha @AbhasKumarSinha.

Comment: @mar For an enlightened person, there is no right or wrong. They exist on the head due to avidya. When the person is realized and enlightened, he gets liberation, even if it means being a butcher.

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha Right and Wrong = Dharma. Following Dharma is essential and is basic to live life. I am not able to understand what you are trying to say

Comment: @river What is dharma or what is adharma is not fixed and is highly dependent on your responsibilities and karma. Hence, it is better to consult your guru around that. A generalized answer is often not correct.

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha Yes, Dharma is not absolute and it is different for every person eg- Varnasharma Dharma is diff for diff varna.
It is written in Gita itself - we should follow our swadharma.  and not  dharma of others.
Though yeah one can abandon one's dharma and do only bhakti of krishna. (Gita 18.66)

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha - being a butcher is not adharmic. u cannot reach to enlightened state by being adharmic. enlightened persons will never do adharma. so your idea that there is no right or wrong is wrong for both non-enlightened and enlightened persons.

Comment: @mar As I've said earlier, what is *dharma* differs for person to person, hence so does *right* and *wrong*. Ashtavakra Mahagita: 1.6 -> **Right and wrong, pleasure and pain,
exist in mind only.
They are not your concern.
You neither do nor enjoy.
You are free.**

Do you seek to contradict Ashtavakra now? If yes, start a new question and send me the link. I'll put an answer.

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha - i'm not questioning ashtavakra. i'm questioning your understanding of him. do you think ashtavakra would commit adharma ? no, he wouldn't because enlightened beings cannot commit adharma - which means they must know what is dharma and adharma. yes, it differs from person to person, doesn't mean it doesn't exist. if any person does adharma (for him), he cannot get moksha.

Comment: @mar If anything enlightened men do is dharmic, then there is no dharma because enlightenment is realizing that everything is unreal except the self. Hence, anything being done/not done is immaterial (beyond the duality of everything), and so becomes dharma which is not the case.